# Why does this SQL query not run in Base SAS?

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

```
proc sql;

select sum(counts) 
from (
      select count(*) "counts" from table1
      union
      select count(*) "counts" from table2
    );
quit;
```

I keep receiving the below error.  I even tried removing the alias.

> ERROR: The SUM summary function requires a numeric argument.
>   ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: counts.

Comment: I guess those are two different errors? you need an alias for your column,

Answer (score 3):

In SAS, identifiers are typically used as not quoted. In case you want identifier containing space or other special character you can use `"identifier"N` to indicate the quoted string is the Name (`"my counts"n` below).

As for the query, I'd use `union all` rather then `union` to sum the counts correctly.

```
proc sql;
create table table1 (x num);
create table table2 (x num);
proc sql;
select sum(counts) as "my counts"n 
from (
      select count(*) as counts from table1
      union all
      select count(*) from table2
    );
quit;
```

For SAS tables, you might get better performance by using row numbers from SAS dictionary tables like this:

```
proc sql;
select sum(nobs - delobs) as "my counts"n 
from dictionary.tables 
where libname = 'WORK' and memname in ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2');
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is giving the inner COUNT(*) results a label, but it is not giving them a variable name.

SAS PROC SQL will let you write code where you don't give your variables names when just doing a SELECT or even when doing a SELECT *.

```
 select count(*) "Total number of rows" from sashelp.class ;
 select * from
   (select count(*) "Label 1" from sashelp.class 
    union all 
    select count(*) "Label 2" from sashelp.class
   )
 ;
```

You can even use them to make datasets, in which case SAS will generate a variable name. Try this:

```
 create table test1 as 
  (select count(*) "Total number of rows" from sashelp.class)
 ;
 describe table test1 ;
```

But if you want to use the variable in an expression like `SUM()` then you have to give the variable a name and not just a label. Otherwise you don't know what to put inside the aggregate function call. In general it is a good idea to give your derived variables names.

```
 select sum(counts) as total_count label="Total of count(*)" from
   (select count(*) as counts from sashelp.class 
    union all 
    select count(*) as counts from sashelp.class
   )
 ;
```

You could try add the `DQUOTE=ANSI` option to your `PROC SQL` statement. This will treat `"name"` as a variable name instead of a string.  But you would still need to add the `AS` keyword before the name.

```
proc sql dquote=ansi;
select sum(counts)
 from (
  select count(*) as "counts" from sashelp.class
  union
  select count(*) as "counts" from sashelp.class
      )
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle if you use identifiers, you always have to refer to the column(s) with those identifiers.Of course if counts is not a reserved word,you can remove them altogether.

```
select sum("counts") 
from (
      select count(*) "counts" from table1
      union
      select count(*) "counts" from table2
    );
quit;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where [tag:oracle] in the question comes from, but the question asks about Base SAS clearly; this wouldn't work in Base SAS.